# How can I idempotently pecl install a module twice?

Tags: linux, bash, pecl

I have a bash script which should be re-runnable. It includes

```
pecl install foo ||
{
    echo "Could not install foo!";
    exit 1;
}
```

If this runs twice, it errors

```
pecl/foo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.2.3
install failed
Could not install foo!
```

Unlike tools such as apt-get or yum, pecl returns an error code if the module is already installed, whereas I want it to report success.

I could capture and grep stdout/stderr but is there a less hacky way of achieving the same?

Comment: Excellent use of the word 'idempotently' - had to look it up, but it perfectly describes the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ! pecl list | grep foo >/dev/null 2>&1;
then
    pecl install foo ||
    {
        echo_err "Could not pecl install foo";
        exit 1;
    }
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

**You could discriminate on *and* mask**

the return value from the `pecl install foo` command with the technique below. It saves the return value from the call, but the 'true' command effectively masks it so the statement returns 0 regardless of the value of `retVal`.

```
pecl install foo >/dev/null 2>&1 || { retVal=$?; true; }
```

**But...**

this won't help much, because `pecl install` appears to return a value of 1 regardless of the nature of the failure - a quick test showed that an already installed package or a package not found error will both return 1.

So instead I would simply check if the package is already installed before calling `pecl install`.

To check if a package is installed I'm assuming the name doesn't include the pecl prefix e.g. jsonc not pecl/jsonc; and that the output from pecl list-all will always start with pecl. To clarify, lets say we are working with package jsonc:

```
 pkg="jsonc"
 pecl list-all | grep "$pkg"
```

Will result in this output (assuming its installed):

> ```
> pecl/jsonc                    1.3.10 JavaScript Object Notation
> ```

To avoid falsely declaring a package installed the regex used with grep leverages that output format - if we simply matched on package name, a match on jsonc would also be a match for jsoncde (not a real package). So the regex is looking for the start of the line to be `pecl/` followed by the package name, with a space after package name : `"^pecl/$pkg "`

You may need to modify that regex based on the possible package names in use.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Package name must be passed as sole argument"
  exit 2
else
  pkg="$1"
fi

if pecl list-all | grep -Eq "^pecl/$pkg " ; then
  echo "package $pkg is already installed"
  exit 0
else # not installed
  if pecl -q install "$pkg" >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Package $pkg installed successfully"
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Error occurred during installation of $pkg"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

If the `pecl list-all | grep ...` command misbehaves when checking for installed packages, you may also be able to use the command `pecl info $pkg`. I didn't look into it much, but it seems to return a 0 (and a bunch of info to stdout) when the package being queried is installed, and returns a 1 when the package isn't installed (and an error to stderr).

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by simply uninstalling the module, as if the module does not exist and you do an uninstall, it returns 0, and since in my case this is a rare job, the extra reinstall does not matter.

Comment: Yes, very good thinking. Similar to _pecl uninstall_ you can also use _pecl upgrade_ which has the benefit to not uninstall: `pecl upgrade <package>`  (Note: works only if you don't specify the package version, so might not always be an option)

Comment: And as seeing it, instead of uninstalling first you can use the `-f` option to force the install.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pretend to install (`-p` option) and then install if it's fine?

```
set -e
if pecl install -p -- "$PACKAGE"; then
  pecl install -- "$PACKAGE"
fi
```